# How to print the number according to the ranks of a student

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
input:
4
22 96 12 49

output:
2  4  1 3
```

What I want in output is the rank of a student according to the input.

However what I was trying til now is going wrong.

```
int count=0;
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a number");
int a =sc.nextInt();
long[] b=new long[a];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
     b[i]=sc.nextLong();
}       
Arrays.sort(b);
for (int j = a-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    System.out.println(b[j]);
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);  
}
```

Comment: `s[]` should be `b[]`, i think its a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take help from the utility [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) Java has! Use `indexOf`, `binarySearch` etc. to find the index of a given element from an array.

```
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number");
    int a =sc.nextInt();
    long[] b = new long[a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
         b[i]=sc.nextLong();
    }       
    long[] tem = new long[a];
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, tem, 0, a);
    Arrays.sort(b);

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
          int res = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(b, tem[i]);
         System.out.print(res + 1 + " ");
    }
```

This program gives:

```
input:
4
22 96 12 49

output:
2  4  1 3
```

Look, if the array is not sorted:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(theArray).indexOf(value)
```

If the array is sorted, you can make use of a binary search for performance:

```
java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(theArray, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the original index in order to print the way you want. 
Instead of creating an integer array, create a 'wrapper' array. So even after sorting,  you know the original index of the element so you will be able to put it's rank in the correct index.

```
      Class Wrapper{
            Int index;
            Int value ;
       }

    Wrapper [] input;
    For(int I=0; I< n ; I++){
           Int value = scan next value;
           Input[i] = new Wrapper (I,value);
    }

   sort input based on value; // ascending order

   Int[] output;
   For(int I=0; I < input.length; I++){
       output[input[i].index] = i+1; // to start the rank from 1.
   }
   Print output array
```